# How to filter specific rows by using seuset of columns values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyBeH.png)

Shown above is my Dataframe image and I want to filter:

1. only columns which are ['lesbian', 'gay', 'bisexual', 'transgender', 'trans','queer', 'lgbt', 'lgbtq', 'homosexual', 'straight','heterosexual']
2. Filter rows where atleast one of the above columns value/s are greater than 0.0. Basically if all 0.0 for the above columns, then remove the row.

The new Dataframe will contain a non-zero value in at least one of the columns in each row.

Tried loop but its not effective. Shd be able to use pandas funtions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do what I believe your question asks:

```py
dfNew = (
    df[['lesbian', 'gay', 'bisexual', 'transgender', 'trans','queer', 'lgbt', 'lgbtq', 'homosexual', 'straight','heterosexual']]
    .pipe(lambda x: x[x.gt(0).any(axis=1)]) )
```

Sample input:

```
   TOXICITY  lesbian  gay  bisexual  transgender  trans  queer  lgbt  lgbtq  homosexual  straight  heterosexual  older  young  younger  teenage  millenial  middle aged
0  0.096492        0    0         0            0   0.00      0     0      0           0         0             0      0      0        0        0          0            0
1  0.017991        0    0         0            0   0.51      0     0      0           0         0             0      0      0        0        0          0            0
2  0.150298        0    0         0            0   0.00      0     0      0           0         0             0      0      0        0        0          0            0
3  0.065861        0    0         0            0   0.00      0     0      0           0         0             0      0      0        0        0          0            0
4  0.667166        0    0         0            0   0.00      0     0      0           0         0             0      0      0        0        0          0            0
```

Output:

```
   lesbian  gay  bisexual  transgender  trans  queer  lgbt  lgbtq  homosexual  straight  heterosexual
1        0    0         0            0   0.51      0     0      0           0         0             0
```

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question? If not, please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Just filter data what columns you want and remove if all columns are 0.

```
df = df.loc[(df[['lesbian', 'gay', 'bisexual', 'transgender', 'trans','queer', 'lgbt', 'lgbtq', 'homosexual', 'straight','heterosexual']] != 0).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: However, I want to keep TOXICITY columns and don't want to remove the row where TOXICITY is 0.0. I want to delete only when all other columns for that row is 0.0 after we filter from the orig. dataset

Comment: I modified my code.